# Hawt.io How to show Heap usage in a line graph?

Tags: java, jmx, hawtio, jolokia

Hawt.io dashboard default shows a donut chart for Heap use.  Its nice, but I want to add a line graph to plot Heap usage over time.  Tried to chart this from the JMX tab but can't graph just the used attribute.  Anyone know how to do this or should I file a bug?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's a one-to-one mapping between an MBean attribute and the available dashboard widget type. Donut chart is the only available widget type for the heap memory usage.
https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/blob/hawtio-1.5.6/hawtio-web/src/main/webapp/app/jmx/js/widgetRepository.ts#L47

You can file an enhancement request for expanding the available widgets for attributes.